# Cannot open include file: 'QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h' on vs2017

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, qt5

[Solved]

Additional include directories should be:

`C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\include`,

not `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets`

as the statement in qapplication.h is `"#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>"`

---

When I was running this on VS2017(x86) on win10, I got the error below:

```
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  return 0;
}

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h'
```

The `qtwidgetsglobal.h` file is just in the directory, but I don't know why VS can't open it.

It seems that compiler can open `QApplication`(is it the same as qapplication.h?), but can't open the first #include file `'qtwidgetsglobal.h'` in QApplication... Why?

I have set the additional include and lib directories in project settings

Additional include directories :

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets
```

Additional lib directories:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\lib
```

I have also installed Qt VS Tools and added the qt version
[qt vs tools options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG0vX.png)

I have also tried the `'winrt_x86_msvc2017'`directory, and it came to the same error. I can't find `'msvc2017'` directory, there's only `'msvc2017_64'`.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you searching in the x64 folders if you are running in x86 ?

Comment: @Kianii I have tried x86 too, and the error is the same,  is `winrt_x86_msvc2017` the folder for vs2017(x86)? I don't know what's the difference between `msvc2017_64` and `winrt_x64_msvc2017`... There's only `winrt_x86_msvc2017` folder and no `msvc 2017`.

Comment: That was not related to your problem anyway : it's not an architecture mismatch error (not yet at least).
I'm very bad at 'debugging' those blinded errors...
For winRT, just make a little search on google and you'll see
But did you try to include the full path and see if VS find it ? If not, it's probably the wrong path/the .h simply does not exist.

Comment: I saw msvc2017 for x86 architecture is not available anymore, they advised to use the msvc2015.

Comment: Don't add the solution to your question. Post an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Additional include directories should be:

`C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\include`,

not `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets`

as the statement in `qapplication.h` is `#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>`